How do I implement "Authorization: Bearer <Token>" in a Delphi REST Server?
I have a working REST server (Sydney) that uses a custom header (AuthToken: 'Token') to authorize users.
When I try to use "Authorization: Bearer 'Token'" as a header in a POST request, I get an exception in my rest server as below. 
It looks like I have to assign a procedure to a TIdHTTPParseAuthenticationEvent, but I cannot find out where to do that.

Yes, you need an OnParseAuthentication event handler for Auth schemes other than Basic. How did you setup your TIdHTTPServer in the first place that you can assign an OnCommandPost handler but not an OnParseAuthentication handler?

I did not setup a TIdHTTPServer sepcifically. I used the wizard in the ide to create a new Datasnap REST Server. I have a project group sharing a TWebModuleUnit that I can use to create a stand alone exe for debugging and then build a DLL that I run under IIS.

Hello Peter, did you completed your project? I've the same issue. On stand-alone I've Form1 and I can assign ParseAuthentication, but when I test it the rsponse is ' Couldn't connect to server'. In ISAPI I do not have at all Form1 and I do not find an FServer instance

When you create a Datasnap REST server project, it creates a default TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge object for you, which is a TIdCustomHTTPServer descendant. You can assign a handler to its OnParseAuthentication event in code (since it is not a visual component on the Form), eg:
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FServer := TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.Create(Self);
  FServer.OnParseAuthentication := ParseAuthentication; // <-- here
end;

procedure TForm1.ParseAuthentication(AContext: TIdContext;
  const AAuthType, AAuthData: String;
  var VUsername, VPassword: String;
  var VHandled: Boolean);
begin
  if TextIsSame(AAuthType, 'Bearer') then begin
    // process AAuthData and assign VUsername and VPassword as needed...
    VHandled := True;
  end;
end;


UPDATE: starting in Indy v10.6.3.3, the TIdCustomHTTPServer.DoParseAuthentication() method is now virtual, so you can alternatively derive a new class from TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge and override it, eg:
type
  TMyHTTPWebBrokerBridge = class(TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge)
  protected
    function DoParseAuthentication(ASender: TIdContext;
      const AAuthType, AAuthData: String;
      var VUsername, VPassword: String): Boolean; override;
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //FServer := TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.Create(Self);
  FServer := TMyHTTPWebBrokerBridge.Create(Self);
end;

function TMyHTTPWebBrokerBridge.DoParseAuthentication(ASender: TIdContext;
  const AAuthType, AAuthData: String;
  var VUsername, VPassword: String): Boolean;
begin
  if TextIsSame(AAuthType, 'Bearer') then begin
    // process AAuthData and assign VUsername and VPassword as needed...
    Result := True;
  end else
    Result := inherited DoParseAuthentication(ASender, AAuthType, AAuthData, VUsername, VPassword);
end;


Thank you for the prompt reply.
